# determine how many documents were ingested into ES server

Tags: elasticsearch

I created one index only called: document. When I run:

```
http://bla:9200/_stats?pretty=true
```

I obtain this (abbreviated):

```
{
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_all" : {
    "primaries" : {
      "docs" : {
        "count" : 31192,
        "deleted" : 32424
      },
      "store" : {
        "size_in_bytes" : 817228373
      },
      "indexing" : {
        "index_total" : 2919822,
        "index_time_in_millis" : 1759994,
        "index_current" : 0,
        "index_failed" : 0,
        "delete_total" : 0,
        "delete_time_in_millis" : 0,
        "delete_current" : 0,
        "noop_update_total" : 0,
        "is_throttled" : false,
        "throttle_time_in_millis" : 0
      },
snip
```

This indicates for me that 2919822 documents where indexed/ingested. It corresponds to the number of documents that were sent to the ES server from my C# code.

However, if I run this:

```
http://bla:9200/_cat/indices?v
```

I get this:

```
health status index    uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   document 8lqJK19xR3yJ7se2sLhWuQ   1   1      31192        32424    778.4mb        778.4mb
```

which indicates that there are only 31192 documents.

Can someone please explain which figure is correct?

PS:

```
http://bla:9200/_cat/count/document?v
```

results in:

```
epoch      timestamp count
1568629672 10:27:52  31522
```

Comment: Can you check your index (using head on chrome for exemple). You can check using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-count.html catcount api too (or count api). If you got only 31k documents instead of 2919822 take a look at es logs + check ids if you force the id fields (duplicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `doc.count` represents the number of documents indexed in your index while `index_total` represents the number of indexing operations performed during elasticsearch uptime.

So if you **update** a document it will count as **one** indexing operation but your `doc.count` won't increase. Please, look at this example where we indexed 2 documents and updated 2 documents using `_bulk` API,

```
POST documents/doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id": 111}}
{"likes": 10, "user": "cs0815", "message": "elastic111"}
{"index":{"_id": 222}}
{"likes": 20, "user": "cs0815", "message": "elastic222"}
{"index":{"_id": 111}}
{"likes": 30, "user": "cs0816", "message": "elastic11111"}
{"index":{"_id": 222}}
{"likes": 40, "user": "cs0816", "message": "elastic22222"}
```

After that we will observe that `doc.count` will be 2 and `index_total` will be 4:

So, in your case you've done `index_total` 2919822, `docs.deleted`  32424 &  `docs.count` 31192 times(along with many duplicate  **updates** based on your id those are counted as 1)

Comment: Thanks - makes sense. I indexed a lot but only had 31192 documents with unique primary key. Not sure what causes the deletes in my code, as I simply sens documents to the server ....

Comment: Could you please tell me where the logs are so that I can try to determine why some documents are not ingested? I use the ingest node to ingest pdfs, word docs and emails ... Thanks!

Comment: I guess this is where you need to look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/logging.html

Comment: Based on your first comment, it seems you've tried to index same unique primary key multiple times, that's why you've less indexed documents compare to index_total  value